# How to retrieve child values from firebase database and display them in a list of layouts?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Fragment class where i want to display a list of layouts where the layout is updated with firebase data values.

This is how my data base looks (user_dubs > user_id > photo id):

[image]

Here's the fragment (**UPDATED**):

```
public class DubsFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "DubsFragment";

//firebase
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference myRef;

//widgets
private EditText mthisdub;
private ListView mListView;

//vars
private ArrayList<String> mDubs;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private Context mContext;
private PostDubs mpostdubs;
private String userID;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mydubs, container, false);

    mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewz);
    mDubs = new ArrayList<>();
    mContext = getActivity();
    mpostdubs = new PostDubs();

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, R.layout.layout_dubs_listitem, R.id.getusername, mDubs);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        setupFirebaseAuth();
    return view;
}

private void setupFirebaseAuth(){
    Log.d(TAG, "setupFirebaseAuth: setting up firebase auth.");

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();

    userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = reference
            .child(getString(R.string.dbname_userdubs))
            .child(userID)
            .orderByChild(getString(R.string.field_photoid));
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    for ( DataSnapshot singleSnapshot :  dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        mpostdubs = singleSnapshot.getValue(PostDubs.class);
                        mDubs.add(mpostdubs.getEditdub().toString());
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}

}
```

Post Dubs Class:

```
public class PostDubs {

    private String editdub;
    private String dubdate;
    private String user_id;
   private String photoid;
    private String username;
    private Context mContext;

    public PostDubs(String user_id, String editdub, String photoid, String dubdate, String username){
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.editdub = editdub;
        this.dubdate = dubdate;
        this.photoid = photoid;
        this.username = username;
    }

    public PostDubs() {

    }


    public String getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public String getEditdub() {
        return editdub;
    }

    public void setEditdub(String editdub) {
        this.editdub = editdub;
    }

    public String getDubdate() {
        return dubdate;
    }

    public void setDubdate(String dubdate) {
        this.dubdate = dubdate;
    }

    public String getPhotoid() {
        return photoid;
    }

    public void setPhotoid(String photoid) {
        this.dubdate = photoid;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "user_id='" + editdub + '\'' +
                ", phone_number='" + dubdate + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

}
```

Here's the layout_dubs_listitem.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
     <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="100dp">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/black"
         app:civ_border_width="0.5dp"
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

     <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profile_image"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true">

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:id="@+id/editdub"
        android:text=""/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
         android:id="@+id/getusername"
        android:text=""/>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

For the test, I'm just trying to get the edit dub in the layout but it is not working at all. I am sure I am doing something stupid.

Please guide me with this problem and it would be very helpful if you could help me update the layout with other child values like username. Thanks.

Comment: Your `ArrayAdapter` has not been given the dataset. That is, you don't pass `mDubs` to `adapter` anywhere, so it has nothing to show. You could pass it in the constructor call as the fourth argument – i.e., `new ArrayAdapter<String>(..., ..., ..., mDubs)` – and then just call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after you've added the items to the list – i.e., after the loop in `onChildAdded()`. If you choose that option, then move the `mListView.setAdapter(adapter)` call to right after the `ArrayAdapter` constructor call, since the `Adapter` itself would never need a new instance created.

Comment: @MikeM. Still not working.. idk why

Comment: Did you see any logs from that `Log.d()` you had in `onChildAdded()`? That is, is that method actually running at all?

Comment: @MikeM.Yes the log "setupFirebaseAuth: setting up firebase auth" is showing

Comment: No, I meant inside `onDataChange()`. You previously had `Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded: child added.");` in `onChildAdded()`. Did you leave the `Log` there in `onDataChange()`?

Comment: Yes I did it was working. I fixed the problem by querying the firebase correctly. Thanks btw !!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by ordering my child in the firebase correctly.